# Openlayers Tracing Image

Tags: openlayers-2, google

Is there a way to load an image into a map div to use as a tracing guide for digitizing features?(*not in geoserver*) Eg: farm paddock layouts from a plan? I would assume you would need to drag, resize and rotate to fit. Like you can currently do in google earth.
Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Please checkout following link might be helpful to pull overlays as reference for tracing.

http://atlantides.org/inscriptol/

http://sgillies.net/blog/691/digitizing-ancient-inscriptions-with-openlayers/

http://floorplanmapper.com/floor-plan-map-employees.php

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/image-layer.html